# Why is replica fetch bytes greater than max message bytes allowed?

Tags: apache-kafka

Recently, we faced an issue in our Kafka cluster where we overrode the `max.message.bytes` value for a topic (which had a replication factor of `3`) to a value larger than `replica.fetch.max.bytes`. We did not see issues immediately but when a message (`replica.fetch.max.bytes` < message size < `max.message.bytes`) was produced later, we started seeing the below error in our logs.

```
Replication is failing due to a message that is greater than replica.fetch.max.bytes for partition [<topic-name>,1]. This generally occurs when the max.message.bytes has been overridden to exceed this value and a suitably large message has also been sent. To fix this problem increase replica.fetch.max.bytes in your broker config to be equal or larger than your settings for max.message.bytes, both at a broker and topic level
```

Since, we did not want to restart our Kafka brokers and perform a rolling upgrade to the cluster immediately, we temporarily decreased the replication factor to `1` (not high availability, I know).

So, are there any useful use cases where such settings might be useful? If yes, what? Also, are there any better solutions that one can try out to mitigate this problem, instead of stopping the replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that since `max.message.bytes` is per topic (and thus stored in ZooKeeper and updated at any point in time), and `replica.fetch.max.bytes` is per broker, it cannot be checked or guaranteed that a topic's `max.message.bytes` is <= a replica's `replica.fetch.max.bytes`.

I also found an old ticket regarding this very problem:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1844

> Kaka Broker on startup checks to see if the configured replica.fetch.max.bytes >= message.max.bytes. But users can override message.max.bytes per topic and there is no such validation happening for per topic message.max.bytes. If the users configured message.max.bytes > replica.fetch.max.bytes , followers won't be able to fetch data.

Also from the documentation about `replica.fetch.max.bytes`, it seems that in some cases it would still work:

> This is not an absolute maximum, if the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this value, the record batch will still be returned to ensure that progress can be made. The maximum record batch size accepted by the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes (topic config).

So all in all, it doesn't seem to make sense and is a known issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think they never addressed that and instead went ahead with allowing dynamic broker configuration as mentioned [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-226+-+Dynamic+Broker+Configuration). This was closed in [KAFKA-6240](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6240) and is available from Kafka 1.1.0. So best alternative is to upgrade the broker settings then.

Answer (score 1):

Brokers allocate a buffer size of `replica.fetch.max.bytes` for each partition they replicate. If `replica.fetch.max.bytes` is set to 1 MiB, and you have 1000 partitions, about 1 GiB of RAM is required.

When the value of `message.max.bytes` (or `max.message.bytes` -topic config)  is grater than the `replica.fetch.max.bytes` it might create situations where the batch wont fit into the allocated buffer. Hence it is important to have `replica.fetch.max.bytes` greater than `message.max.bytes`. The broker will still accept messages but fail to replicate them. Leading to potential data loss

The value of `max.message.bytes` is usually increased to have higher throughput.  Or the size of each message is larger than 1mb(Default value)
Please ensure that the number of partitions multiplied by the size of the largest message does not exceed available memory.

As for the solution, `replica.fetch.max.bytes` is a read only broker level config soo a restart will be required

Comment: Sorry, but I already knew this. How does this explain why one might keep `max.message.bytes` higher than `replica.fetch.max.bytes`?